# How use Hibernate Tools to execute JPQL Queries?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-tools

I need to make some tests with JPQL, so I'm trying do that with Hibernate Tools, but when I try open the session factory appears this : **Could not locate TransactionManager** as showed below:

[image]

Here is my `persistence.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="SuaParte">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/suaparte_ds</jta-data-source>
        <class>entity.Area</class>
            //classes..
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="jdbc/suaparte_ds"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after a long search for solution I found one publication.

I tried the advice given in the link [Hibernate tools: Could not find datasource](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2400465) and it worked.